# Trouble to open application on Blackberry Simulator

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-jde

I am trying to open my application on simulator 9800.i am using JDE 6.0.when i tried to debug my application i got some message on my console.

> [0.0] UIE: Foreground app package.MyApp@ has no screens.  This should be corrected.
>   [0.0] UIE: Foreground app package.MyApp@ ignoring touchscreen touch/click because it has no targ[0.0] et screen.

My other applications are working fine.I have reinstalled my simulator but still probelm is occuring.need your suggestions.

Comment: its happening frequently now.sometimes application gets open sometimes not.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes clean and rebuild solves this problem, did you tried?

Comment: is it possible that problem could be in coding?

Answer (score 0):

Experiencing the same issue, with device B-9900.

Re-installation of application helped me in solving the problem.